# Daemon-kit process one amqp job at a time

Tags: ruby, rabbitmq, daemon, amqp

We've used daemon-kit to create a amqp worker which should receive a job and then ask for a new job, but not before the first job is finished. The problem is that Daemon Kit forkes the job and immediately starts a new job if there is one in the RabbitMQ queue.

Is there a formal way to force one-job-at-a-time-behaviour in daemon-kit? Or how can we achieve this?

This is a short version of how we start the amqp worker and process jobs. When a job finishes with a result it publishes this back to the RabbitMQ server.

```
# Run an event-loop for processing
DaemonKit::AMQP.run do |connection|

  connection.on_tcp_connection_loss do |client, settings|
    DaemonKit.logger.debug("AMQP connection status changed: #{client.status}")
    client.reconnect(false, 1)
  end

  amq = AMQP::Channel.new

  amq.queue(engine_key).subscribe do |metadata,msg|

    msg_decode = JSON.parse(msg)

    job = REFxEngineRunnerAPI10.new msg_decode
    result = job.run(metadata.correlation_id)

    amq.queue( metadata.reply_to, :auto_delete => false)

    xc = amq.default_exchange
    xc.publish JSON.dump(result), :routing_key => metadata.reply_to, :correlation_id => metadata.correlation_id
  end
end
```

**UPDATE**

I found this to work for us:

```
DaemonKit::AMQP.run do |connection|

  amq = AMQP::Channel.new(connection, prefetch: 1)
  # I needs this extra line because I use RabbitMQ new than version 2.3.6
  amq.qos(0, 1) 

  # be sure to add (:ack => true)
  amq.queue(engine_key).subscribe(:ack => true) do |metadata,msg|

    #### run long job one at a time

    # Tell RabbitMQ I finished the job and I can now receive a new job
    metadata.ack

  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm taking a stab in the dark here, since this sounds to me exactly how the protocol should behave. You can however using *QoS* or *prefetching* to limit the number of messages sent down to a subscriber from the broker using something like this:

`amq = AMQP::Channel.new(connection, prefetch: 1)`

According to [the example](http://rubyamqp.info/articles/working_with_queues/#toc_22) this should give you the behaviour your desire.